# How to grep names of files, which contain simultaneusly a few words

Tags: command-line, grep

I did the following:

```
for i in ~/files/*; do cat $i | grep -e word1 -e word2; done
```

The output was: all the values, which contain word1 and alongside it - all the files, which contain word2. Not only which contain both of them. And I wanted files' names as well, not just values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can use `grep`’s `-H` option to “[p]rint the file name for each match”.

This will find lines which contain `word1` **or** `word2`:

```bsh
grep -HE "word1|word2" ~/files/* 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to find lines with `word1` **and** `word2`, instead do:

```bsh
grep -HE "word1.*word2|word2.*word1" ~/files/* 2>/dev/null
```

Sending stderr to a dark oblivion with `2>/dev/null` prevents `grep` from outputting useless error messages, e.g. if one of the matched files is a directory.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk Corrected, thanks a lot! I wrote this with less skill than I have today… ;)

Comment: @damadam That’s a nice trick, but there’s actually no need if `grep` provides an option for this. It’s worth mentioning that I’m talking about GNU `grep` here, `-H` may not be available in other builds.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` usually prints lines matching *any* of the provided patterns. To print lines matching multiple patterns, pipe the output of one grep to another:

```
grep word1 | grep word2
```

For many files:

```
grep word1 ~/files/* | grep word2
```

No need for a loop or `cat`.

This may not work correctly for files whose names contain `word2`. In that case, combine the patterns manually into a single grep:

```
grep -e 'word1.*word2' -e 'word2.*word1' ~/files/*
```

When multiple files are provided to `grep`, it prints the filename by default. To force this for a single filename, use `-H`:

```
-H, --with-filename
      Print the file name for each match.  This is  the  default  when
      there is more than one file to search.
```

If you get an error about argument list being too long, and the directory doesn't contain subdirectories, I'd still tell `grep` to recurse:

```
grep -R -e 'word1.*word2' -e 'word2.*word1' ~/files
```

Comment: There were too many files, so I got: 'list is too long' or sometning, like this, so I was going for loop. Another thing: if I will do grep to grep - it will work only with output of the first grep and not with original file.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk see last command for that case. And add such errors to the question, please.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk that's the whole point. If you want lines matching both patterns, you will have to either use complex regex like in the third command, or pipe to the another grep.